# $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely does $\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,a](X_n)}$ converges to $\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,a](X)}$? give an example.

Tags: probability-theory

Give an example to show that we can not conclude $\mathbb{1}_{(−∞,a]}(X_n)$
converges to $\mathbb{1}_{(−∞,a]}(X)$ a.s. (almost surely).

Comment: For _some_ $a$? Or for _every_ $a$?

Comment: @kimchilover for every a

Answer (score 3):

Not even true for deterministic (constant) $X_n$.  Say $a=0$, $X_n = 1/n$, $X=0$.  Then $X_n \to X$, but $1_{(-\infty,0](X_n)} = 0$ and $1_{(-\infty,0](X)}=1$.